# List of github repositories into a symfony 2 / eZPlatform project

Tags: git, symfony, github-api, ezplatform

I am currently working on a project to learn the CMS eZPlatform, which use the fullstack of Symfony.
We want to list all the repositories of our github account.

Reading the GitHub API, I do not understand well. To list the repositories of an organisation, I have to use

```html
curl -i https://api.github.com/orgs/mozilla/repos
```

The thing is (and sorry if it is a dumb question) : where do I put this line , how can I do to have this list?

I already create the route, the template and the controller which will do the logic. But I am completly lost and do not understand.

PS: First time using an API => learning everyday

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` is a console binary that can be used to make a request to a web server from the command line—see [the `curl` home page](https://curl.haxx.se)—and that's what GitHub's example code is showing to you.

For integration with Symfony, you should seek out a PHP GitHub API library. I can't make specific recommendations, but [this page](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) lists some.